How to whitelist websites in Edubuntu while blocking all other websites?
I would like to block all website access except for a whitelist in Edubuntu LTS 24.04 for a child user.
The child should only have access to a number of websites specifically whitelisted by a parent or guardian.
How can this be achieved?

There are so many ways to do this. One way that many Linux users will frown upon is to install Microsoft Edge and create a child account which you can manage from the Microsoft Accounts page. By default, Microsoft will restrict websites available to the child, but you can put additional restrictions in place. Additionally, you'll get a weekly report of what sites the child has attempted to access without your permission, or alert you if the child wants permission to access a site, i.e. for a school project.
Unfortunately, that's not very "freedom-loving" and does require checking the box to hide the Firefox icon in "Edubuntu Menu Administrator" or uninstalling it altogether (sudo snap remove firefox) which might be a bit overkill depending on your usage needs.
Another solution can be done at the DNS level either on the computer or at the router level with OpenDNS Family Shield, but that doesn't have nearly the comprehensive control that Microsoft Edge offers.
Firefox recommends using third-party software and extensions, which is a reason why it might be a good idea to use a different browser for parental controls. Sadly, other browsers with built-in comprehensive parental controls, such as Microsoft Edge, cannot be shipped with Edubuntu, as they have proprietary licenses and Ubuntu doesn't have redistribuition rights.
